# Redirect stdout and stderr to file permanently but keep printing them

Tags: bash

By doing the following(1):

```
 exec >> log_file
 exec 2>&1
 ls
```

`stdout` and `stderr` is permanently redirected for the next commands but not anymore displayed on terminal. Here, `ls` output will be in `log_file` but not displayed in terminal

By doing the following(2):

```
command | tee log_file
```

`command` output will be both in `log_file` and printed on terminal but this will work only for `command` and not for the next commands as method 1.

How to redirect permanently `stdout` and `stderr` output in a file for a given terminal like method 1 and, keep `stdout` and `stderr` printed on the terminal instance like method 2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I currently use this in my scripts:

```
exec > >(tee -a "${FILE_Log}" )
exec 2> >(tee -a "${FILE_Log}" >&2)
```

Basically you are telling bash to send the output (both `stdout` and `stderr`) to `tee`'s `stdin`, and since `tee` is running in the subshell (within the parentheses), it will live as long as your script does.

Put that somewhere near the top, then any and all `command` output, `echo`, `print`, and, `printf` will be logged.

This saves having to create a `LOG()` function and constantly piping commands to `tee`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is Very close to what i need! when you send a signal to your script does it make bash crash?

Comment: I don't believe it will. I have not tested sending signals to it. I believe it will continue to run.

Comment: For me it results in a bash crash unfortunately

Comment: What signal are you passing to your script?

Comment: I send a SIGINT signal

Comment: This method is unfortunately flaky: the current script will complete and exit, and return to the user's prompt (or to continuing in some higher-level calling script), before the tee finishes writing the log file and before it finishes writing to normal stdout and stderr.  Bad consequences include: (1) the prompt appears before the last few lines of output to user's terminal, (2) a subsequent command that expects the log file to be complete will not see the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tee` and redirection combined:

```
(exec 2>&1) | tee file.txt
```

Here's an example

```
[root@box ~]# (ll 2>&1) | tee tmp.txt
total 4
-rw-------. 1 root root 1007 Apr 26  2017 anaconda-ks.cfg
[root@box ~]# cat tmp.txt
total 4
-rw-------. 1 root root 1007 Apr 26  2017 anaconda-ks.cfg
```

The reason the command is inside paranthesis is to keep the order of the prints, since stdout is buffered. It causes the `ll` command to be executed in a subshell, and then return the output of stdout + stderr in-order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this unfortunately does not work... the example work only for the "ll" command and not the next commands used.
The solution does not work at all

Comment: echo, ls, any command, but doing (exec 2>&1) | tee logfile before executing them will not put their output in logfile

Comment: @Thomas Kostas This direction is not related above issue directly, but I think you add `-a` to `tee` command. `tee -a logfile` can be added the output to logfile at every executing.

Comment: @ThomasKostas try executing it without the paranthesis as exec opens its own subshell (I thought you just used it for a general name of a command..)

Comment: This is a very confusing answer.   The question is using `exec` to mean, literally, `exec`, but it looks like you have repurposed it to mean something else (a placeholder for a general other command?) And, even if one figures that out, this isn't an answer to the question, which is asking how to control output of *all* subsequent commands, not just one command.

Answer (score 0):

Hickory420's answer cannot be used in sh. After searching online for a long time, I finally found a way to use it in sh, bash or any shell.

```bash
# Redirect the stdout/stderr to screen AND log file

mkfifo /tmp/$$-err /tmp/$$-out
# to merge stdout/stderr to log file AND screen
( exec tee -a ${FILE_LOG} </tmp/$$-out ) &
( exec tee -a ${FILE_LOG} </tmp/$$-err >&2 ) &

exec 1>/tmp/$$-out
exec 2>/tmp/$$-err
rm -f /tmp/$$-out /tmp/$$-err
```

refer: [Redirect STDOUT & STDERR to file and then on screen](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/279967-redirect-stdout-stderr-file-then-screen.html)